# How to call jar function from Jruby?

Tags: java, jar, jruby

I've tried a few methods and this is the closest yet - how can the maths library be called from a jruby script?

```
require 'java'
require 'commons-math3-3.2.jar'

import org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomGenerator

myClass = RandomGenerator.new

puts "hello!"

puts myClass.nextBoolean()
```

The error that is returned is NoMethodError: undefined method `nextBoolean' for #<#:0x7816fcc4>

Answer (score 3):

OK. Got it working.

```
require 'java'
require 'commons-math3-3.2.jar'

Randy = org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomDataGenerator 
jp = Randy.new

puts jp.nextInt(10,20)
```